# Unity 2d: Camera resets when beginning to drag

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

So I am trying to move the camera through dragging with the mouse and it works but everytime I begin to drag again, the camera resets to 0, 0 and I don't understand why.
Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera cam;
    Vector2 mouseOffset;
    Vector2 dragOffset;
    Vector3 mousePosition;
    Vector3 mousePixPos;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //From Mouse Position in Pixel to Worldposition
        mousePixPos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePixPos.z = cam.nearClipPlane;
        mousePosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePixPos);
        

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            mouseOffset = new Vector2(mousePosition.x - transform.position.x, mousePosition.y - transform.position.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            dragOffset = new Vector2(mousePosition.x - mouseOffset.x, mousePosition.y - mouseOffset.y);
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - dragOffset.x, transform.position.y - dragOffset.y, -10);
        }
    }

}
```

The MouseOffset is the Offset of the mouse from the camera meaning the middle of the gamescreen. The dragOffset is the Offset of the mouse from the earlier set MouseOffset. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera cam;
    Vector2 dragOffset;
    Vector3 mousePosition;
    Vector3 mousePixPos;
    Vector3 mouseStartPos;
    Vector3 myStartPos;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //From Mouse Position in Pixel to Worldposition
        mousePixPos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePixPos.z = cam.nearClipPlane;
        mousePosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePixPos);
        

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            mouseStartPos = mousePixPos;
            myStartPos = transform.position;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            dragOffset = new Vector2(mousePixPos.x - mouseStartPos.x, mousePixPos.y - mouseStartPos.y);
            transform.position = new Vector3(myStartPos.x - dragOffset.x, myStartPos.y - dragOffset.y, myStartPos.z);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It works but now the camera is bugging and teleporting left and right

Comment: When does it teleport?

Comment: I tested and the dragOffset is changing even if I don't move the mouse

Comment: Then it just swaps between 2 Values

Comment: Oh I see. Two seconds I will edit it.

Comment: It's a bit fast now but it works. Thanks very much

Comment: Yea its in a different coordinate space than before, just try scaling it.